Dynamically inserted html() elements are not click() event functional, non-interactive
I am using jquery-ui dialog to display editable page data and mostly works well except for the page delete process to reload the updated navigation elements. The process occurs in the AJAX success function to replace the existing nav container with new returned values.
The delete action works correctly on first use and the "correct" visual HTML is inserted with $("#pagelist").html(data.links.join("")); but then the click actions are not functional unless the entire page is reloaded.
How can I update the elements and have interactive function?
Minified coding
The following is just extract of the coding with focus on the delete process
javascript
$(function() 
{
    $("#modalHtml").dialog({
        autoOpen: false,
        height: 720,
        width: "90%",
        modal: true,
        closeOnEscape: true,
        classes: {"ui-dialog": "the-modal"},
        buttons: []
    });
    
    $("#modal_Open_Button").click(function() {
        $("#modalHtml").dialog("open");
    });
    
    // nav item delete
    $("#pagelist").find(".pagelist-del").each(function(i,v) 
    {
        $(v).on("click",function(e) 
        {
            let pgid = $(this).data("page-delete");
            
            $.post("ajax.php", {
                action: "page_delete",
                delid: pgid,
                tbl: "shows"
            }).done(function(data) {
// reload navigation elements.
// this works fine only for the display
// but none of the click() events function unless the page is reloaded
                $("#pagelist").html(data.links.join(""));
            });
        });
        return;
    });
});

HTML
<button id="modal_open_button">Open Modal</button>
<div id="modalHtml" title="Shows" style="display: none;">
    <div id="pagelist">
        <div class="flex flexmid gap2">
            <span data-page-edit="1" class="pagelist-link" title="edit page">The new show</span>
            <span data-page-disable="1" title="disable">/</span>
            <span data-page-delete="1" class="pagelist-del" title="delete">X</span>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>

ajax.php
if( file_exists($req->tbl.'/'.$req->delid.'.json') ) 
{
    $tbl = $req->tbl;
    $pagefile = $tbl.'/'.$req->delid.'.json';
    $img = json_decode(file_get_contents($pagefile));
    $img = $img->image;
    
    unlink($tbl.'/'.$img);
    unlink($pagefile);
    
    $datafiles = filelist($tbl,'.json',true); // scandir() process
    natsort($datafiles);
    $lastId = (int)basename(end($datafiles));

    $pages=[];
    foreach($datafiles as $k => $dbfile) 
    {
        $pgid = (int)basename($dbfile);
        $data = file_get_contents($dbfile);
        $data = json_decode($data);
        $pages[] = '
        <div class="flex flexmid gap2">
            <span data-page-edit="'.$pgid.'" class="pagelist-link" title="edit page">'.$data->title.'</span>
            <span data-page-disable="'.$pgid.'" title="disable">/</span>
            <span data-page-delete="'.$pgid.'" class="pagelist-del" title="delete">X</span>
        </div>';
    }
    // method to return JSON data to AJAX success function
    jsdata([
    'notice'=>'Page deleted successfully',
    'class'=>'success',
    'links'=>$pages,
    'lastid'=>$lastId
    ]);
}

Display


No it does not. I had already used many options of parent - child formats to get results and all failed, hence my inquiry here

Please show how you tried to apply it. It should be something like $("#modalHtml").on("click", ".pagelist-del", function...)

You have a typo here: $("#modal_Open_Button") it should be $("#modal_open_button")

@Barmar I really don't know what more clarity can be written in the post. The process occurs within a loop which is shown in javascript. The delete action works properly for a single first use when the page is loaded, but fails for additional deletions after the element update at $("#pagelist").html(data.links.join(""));

You shouldn't have that loop. The delegation I showed above takes its place.

That should be explained in the linked question. You claim you tried to apply that solution, so that's what you need to show in the post.

@Barmar you are correct about not using the loop. I figured it was right for retrieving the ID per element on click event, but that clearly defeated the purpose of the data attribute. The parent / child binding now works and continuous delete is functional. Thanks for the guide.

Closed as answered by an existing question, based on the above comment (and this question's title and code content...)
